# C# three dimensional array, convert row to array

Tags: c#, .net, linq, algorithm

```
var examples = new double[1000][][];

 for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
 {
  examples[i]= new double[2][]; //the Set
  examples[i][0] = new double[] { x(i), y(i) }; //the Inputs
  examples[i][1] = new double[] { Math.Sin(x(i) * y(i)), Math.Sin(x(i) / y(i)) }; //the Target
 }
```

`x(i)` means `x` depend on `i`

And I need to collect the inputs like that `examples[][0] = new double[1000][]`
because It will consume more memory to create a new array like that

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
   input[i][0]=x(i);
   input[i][1]=y(i);
}
```

Comment: Does that first line, `new double[1000][][]` even compile?

Comment: ? it's a simple jagged array , it does compile

Comment: @sarnold, yes. It initializes an array of 1000 other jagged arrays.

Comment: @Anthony: thanks! This is the first I've seen that C# drastically relaxed the C/C++ array type rules. :)

Comment: Is there a good reason you are using a fixed size array rather than a list of object references? Nevertheless, I don't see a question here.

Comment: Question was just how to collect the 1000 arrays of input {x,y} working with matrix so I have to use fixed size , I am very bad at programming but I hope beginners are welcomed here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would be to reconsider the design decision that ended up with a [1000][2][2] array which you want to pull a flattened [1000][2] array out of by taking a specific center-array value...

As far as accessing it without re-allocating memory, you're not going to get it as an array without using more memory sorry, but what you could do is get an `IEnumerable<double[]>` which may suffice depending on your purposes by using `yield` (Which will make it evaluate each result individually as you enumerate over it).

EG:

```
public IEnumerable<double[]> GetResults()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; x++)
  {
    yield return examples[i][0];
  }
}
```

How useful that is will depend on how you plan to use the results, but you won't get a new array without using more memory.

Comment: Ok I will try with objects Example made of Input and Target arrays, and see how it goes Thank you